# Implement pkg_resources.resource_filename in setuptools

Tags: python, pkg-resources, symspellpy

I am working to incorporate the symspellpy package for spell checking and correcting large amounts of data. However, the package suggests using pkg_resources.resource_filename, which is no longer supported. Can you please provide guidance on how to access the necessary resources using the currently preferred method?

```py
dictionary_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename("symspellpy", "frequency_dictionary_en_82_765.txt")
bigram_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename("symspellpy", "frequency_bigramdictionary_en_243_342.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement is the `importlib_resources.files` function.
It is integrated in standard library from Python 3.9, as `importlib.resources.files`

If you just need to support Python 3.9 or newer, it's straightforward

```py
import importlib.resources

importlib.resources.files(...)
```

Otherwise, if you want to support Python 3.8 and older, here's how you do it:

1. add `importlib_resources>=1.3; python_version < '3.9'` to your dependencies (`requirements.txt`, `setup.cfg`, `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`, depending how the project is organised)
2. In your code, adapt as

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
    import importlib.resources as importlib_resources
else:
    import importlib_resources

importlib_resources.files(...)
```

See https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html